# Intermittent Ubuntu 18.04 upgrade to 20.04 when 22.04 is available

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ubuntu-18.04

I'd like to upgrade Ubuntu 18.04 to 20.04, But now 22.04 is available, So it's always ended with the 22.xx version. I'm looking for a way to stop at 20.04 version. I don't want to go directly from 18.04 to 22.xx version.

I tried through CLI.

Comment: You can find 20.04 on this list   ....   https://ubuntu.com/download/alternative-downloads  ... You would have to download and update yourself.

Comment: Hi @John, Thanks for quick response, But I don't need to download/install Ubuntu OS, I have to upgrade the existing Ubuntu 18.04 OS to 20.04 without data loss.

Comment: I don't think that will work. The Ubuntu Updater will take you to 22.04 (which I am using).  If you need to stay at 20.04 you will have to do it yourself.